# Does a coroutine prevent an object from being garbage collected?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I've seen tutorials where writing to Room performed in a coroutine launched using viewModelScope, so it's cancelled when ViewModel is destroyed. But I want data to be written in any case. So I want to launch this coroutine in a scope that doesn't depend on Activity's lifecycle.

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
  val applicationScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())
}
```

Is it true that if I launch a long-running coroutine in ViewModel using this scope ViewModel won't be allowed to be garbage collected until the coroutine is finished even if Activity is destroyed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True. Launching a long-running coroutine from everywhere will retain objects that it references until it's finished or cancelled.

That's why it's advisable to use `viewModelScope` when inside `ViewModel` and `lifecycleScope` in activities and fragments. Because they know how to cancel those jobs.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines

But if you don't reference your activity or context (which is actually the activity itself) they won't leak.

```
   CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())
            .launch { 
                // activity.getString(R.string.something) // Memory leak!
                applicationContext.getString(R.string.something) // Memory leak on applicationContext but not on activity. That's fine.

            }
. . .
   }
```

Or at least that's how I'd expect it to work. But there seems to be an unexpected behavior when you do `withContext(NonCancellable)` inside there. See https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1061.

In short, write it so there's no references to `Activity` and other objects that reference `Activity`, as is good practice. Otherwise expect things to leak. I'd say the same if you reference any `viewmodel` objects inside a coroutine.

Comment: This is an excellent answer but I think it's worth pointing out to people that there is no "fine" memory leaks, and that referencing the application's context isn't a memory leak itself, since the Application object would never be eligible for garbage collection since it's constantly running and needed anyway, i.e. it's OK to reference it in scopes with smaller lifecycles.